# variable auto-refresh xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, variables, xamarin

I have a (strange) problem on my activity, when i pass from one activity to another (create map --> play), i save a copy (the original map) of my "state" variable (in OnCreate method) for restore it when the user will click the "restart" button (the original "state" variable is edited during the execution of the activity). But inexplicably (for me) the copy variable is updated like the original. What is the mistake??

```
int[,] state = new int[10,10];

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.step_by_step);
        int[] array = Intent.GetIntArrayExtra("arrayintero");
        //re-convert the array in 2D-array
        int[,] initial = new int[10, 10];
        int conta = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                state[i, j] = array[conta]
                conta++;
            }
        }
        //initial is the copy variable
        initial = state;
        //update the map
        update_draw(buttonArray, state);

        //when the restart button is clicked
        restart.Click += delegate
        { 
            Toast.MakeText(this, "restart", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            //restore the map 
            update_draw(buttonArray, initial);
            //update the original variable
            state = initial;                
        };
```

Comment: c# arrays are objects, so you are simply creating two pointers to the same object.

Comment: thank you @Jason !  i have used ' Array.Copy(state,0, initial, 0,100); '

Answer (score 0):

**solution**

```
Array.Copy(state,0, initial, 0,100)
```

Thank You to @Jason